# Guzzle - Elasticsearch - Bulk API

Tags: php, elasticsearch, guzzle, bulk

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch Bulk API with guzzle but I don't know what is the correct format for the body.

When I do it with curl, I don't have any problem.

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/hakuna/matata/_bulk" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Abc", "category": "Alphabet", "tags": ["premier", "alphabet"], "duration": 40}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Def", "category": "Alphabet", "tags": ["second", "alphabet"], "duration": 50}
{"index": {}}
{"title": "Ghi", "category": "Alphabet", "tags": ["troisieme", "alphabet"], "duration": 60}
'
```

When I do it with guzzle, I always get this error

```
 Client error: `POST http://localhost:9200/hakuna/matata/_bulk` resul  
  ted in a `400 Bad Request` response:                                         
  {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reas  
  on":"Validation Failed: 1: no requests added; (truncated...)
```

This is the php code

```
        $data = [
            json_encode(['index' => []]),
            json_encode(['title' => 'Abc', 'category' => 'Alphabet', 'tags' => ['premier', 'alphabet'], 'duration' => 40]),
            json_encode(['index' => []]),
            json_encode(['title' => 'Def', 'category' => 'Alphabet', 'tags' => ['second', 'alphabet'], 'duration' => 50]),
            json_encode(['index' => []]),
            json_encode(['title' => 'Ghi', 'category' => 'Alphabet', 'tags' => ['troisieme', 'alphabet'], 'duration' => 60]),
        ];

        $data = join("\n", $data);

        $response = $client->post('hakuna/matata/_bulk', [
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
            'json' => $data,
        ]);
```

I've tried with a normal array without json_encode and without the string transformation, but I always get the same error.

**EDIT : The final working code**

```
        $data = [
            json_encode(['index' => []], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT),
            json_encode(['title' => 'Abc', 'category' => 'Alphabet', 'tags' => ['premier', 'alphabet'], 'duration' => 40]),
            json_encode(['index' => []], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT),
            json_encode(['title' => 'Def', 'category' => 'Alphabet', 'tags' => ['second', 'alphabet'], 'duration' => 50]),
            json_encode(['index' => []], JSON_FORCE_OBJECT),
            json_encode(['title' => 'Ghi', 'category' => 'Alphabet', 'tags' => ['troisieme', 'alphabet'], 'duration' => 60]),
        ];

        $data = join("\n", $data);

        $response = $client->post('hakuna/matata/_bulk', [
            'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
            'body' => $data."\n",
        ]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right path, nice effort so far!

All you need to do now is to add a newline character at the end of each line **including the last one**, like this:

```
    $data = [
        json_encode(['index' => []]),
        json_encode(['title' => 'Abc', 'category' => 'Alphabet', 'tags' => ['premier', 'alphabet'], 'duration' => 40]),
        json_encode(['index' => []]),
        json_encode(['title' => 'Def', 'category' => 'Alphabet', 'tags' => ['second', 'alphabet'], 'duration' => 50]),
        json_encode(['index' => []]),
        json_encode(['title' => 'Ghi', 'category' => 'Alphabet', 'tags' => ['troisieme', 'alphabet'], 'duration' => 60]),
    ];

    $data = join("\n", $data);

    $response = $client->post('hakuna/matata/_bulk', [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        'body' => $data . '\n';                   <--- change this line
    ]);
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, you need to use `body` instead of  `json` in order to send raw data

Comment: yes, that's it! Thank you so much.
Just one more thing. I needed to add `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` as second argument of the `json_encode` in order to have an object  `{}` for the empty array after the transformation, instead of an array

Comment: I believe that the last line must be "\n" instead of '\n'